# Use fourier transform to solve wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Here's the question.

$\frac{∂^2}{∂t^2 } u(x,t)=c^2  \frac{∂^2}{∂x^2 } u(x,t)$

We are supposed to use this form of Fourier transform to solve our PDE

$\hat{f(s)} = \frac{1}{√2π} ∫_{-∞}^∞f(t) e^{(-ist)} dt$

Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this question?

Thanks!

Comment: The site works best for Questions that have identified something the Asker wants to learn.  When a problem is posted verbatim from an assignment, with no indication what was tried and what difficulty was encountered, Readers are left in the dark as to whether they are being asked not to educate the poster, but to do their thinking for them.

Answer (score 3):

Observe what happens when you take the Fourier transform of a derivative:
$$\begin{align}\widehat{\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)}(k) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^{-ikx}dx = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( e^{-ikx} \right) dx \\ &= ik \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u e^{ikx} dx = ik \hat{u}(k),\end{align}$$ (why? you should justify each step to yourself). So $$\widehat{\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)}(k) = ik \hat{u}(k).  $$ So the Fourier transform of a second derivative then is $$\widehat{\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)}(k) = (ik)^2 \hat{u}(k) = -k^2 \hat{u}(k).$$ Let's take the **Fourier transform in x** of your equation now:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \hat{u}(k,t) = c^2 (-k^2) \hat{u}(k,t) = -c^2 k^2 \hat{u}(k,t),$$ which is a differential equation in $t$ that contains no $x$-derivatives. You can integrate this (again, if you can't see this immediately you should work it out for yourself): $$\hat{u}(k,t) = Ae^{ickt} + Be^{-ickt}$$ for some constants $A$ and $B$. It now remains to invert the Fourier transform of $\hat{u}(k,t)$. Can you finish it off?