# How to impose the boundary conditions on $u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk\left[A(k)e^{ik(x-ct)}+B(k)e^{ik(x+ct)}\right]$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

Using the method of Fourier transform, the solution of one-dimensional wave equation $$\left(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)u(x,t)=0$$ turns out to be ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1530083/470941)) $$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk\left[A(k)e^{ik(x-ct)}+B(k)e^{ik(x+ct)}\right].$$ Now if we are given a set of boundary conditions (i) $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ and $u(a,0)=b$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0$, how do we impose these efficiently? In particular, how to show the that the $k$-values become discrete?

Comment: Those boundary conditions are not enough to make the $k$-values discrete. You need to add that $u$ shall be periodic in $x$.

Comment: @md2perpe If we want this general solution to describe the vibration of a string fixed at $x=0$ and $x=L$, what sort of periodicity (or periodicities) do we need to impose?

Comment: There are several choices like 1) $u(x+L,t)=u(x,t)$ and 2) $u(-x,t)=-u(x,t)$ and $u(x+2L,t)=-u(x,t).$